# Two Ternary Operators in One Twig Statement

Tags: twig

I am using two different ternary operators to conditionaly add classes using twig.  Here is what my code looks like:

```
class="topbar-links {{ dropdown ? 'topbar-links__dropdown' }} {{ cta ? 'topbar-links__cta' }}"
```

I am wondering if it is really necessary for me to close the first ternary statement with ending curly brackets and then immediately start a new ternary statement with opening curly brackets.  Is there some way to combine this in one statement?  Perhaps something like this:

```
class="topbar-links {{ dropdown ? 'topbar-links__dropdown', cta ? 'topbar-links__cta' }}"
```

Now this does **not** work - but it's the type of thing I am looking for.  In short, some way to simplify the code.  Is something like this possible?  If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with

```
class="topbar-links{{ (dropdown ? ' topbar-links__dropdown') ~ (cta ? ' topbar-links__cta') }}"
```

Comment: Bit more straightforward than my solution ^^

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know where I can learn about this on the twig docs?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be to populate an array I guess

```html
class="topbar-links {{ [ topbar ? 'topbar-links__dropdown', cta ? 'cta-links__dropdown', ]|filter(v => v)|join(' ') }}"
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/atpgcm)